# How is it to have User and Role info in Windows Azure Table Storage Accounts for system Authentication

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-table-storage

I am designing a web application -  to display the data on the UI from Table Storage.
I have decided to go for *Table Storage* as there are **no relationship between the 25+ tables that I am expected to have in the storage account**.

**My requirement is to Authenticate User**
I would like to restrict anonymous access in my application.To authenticate the user, my plan is to create an User table and  Role and UserRole tables in Azure Table Storage Account. These 3 tables obviously have relationship within each other. Except these 3, rest all other 25+ tables are standalone tables.

**Authentication will happen** in the application querying the user,role tables in TableStorage when a functionality is accessed by an user.

**My Queries**

Is this a good design?

Do we have any risk in this design?

If not what is an alternate option for this?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to take a look at [Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-whatis) and [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) and use this as a *Identity management as a Service* (IDaaS).

Then you *don't* have to store users and roles within your storage account and don't have to worry about security holes.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Let me go thru' and utilize it.
Do we have any extra cost included if we go for this?

Comment: Probably not. But this depends on your requirements. There is a premium AAD tier that enables addination features like self service password reset etc...

Comment: I have gone thru' it. Its seems to be similar to the FaceBookAuthentication, GoogleAuthentication ...
I think this would work out for us.
Thanks Martin.